# How to avoid users see data from other user socket?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I have a dasboard that is making socket request every five seconds, sometimes, some users start getting data from other user socket request, but at the begging everything is working fine.

I have tried with sticky-session, diferrent socket instance, personalized socket event names.

if someone unsderstand my problem and i have a solution, i would be grateful.

Comment: Have you try giving every client a distinct `room`?

You can easily create new room based on `clientID`

https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/

Answer (score 0):

Sockets are, by definition, separate from each other. I suspect the issue is that you're emitting to a namespace rather than to a particular socket.

```
io.of('someNamespace').emit('data');
```

vs

```
io.of('someNamespace').on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('data');
});
```

In the first example we're sending data to *all* sockets in the namespace. In the second we're only sending data to a particular socket. The difference is in where you're emitting the data.